# How to establish the New service connection for EKS in AzureDevOps?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I want to create CI/CD for deploying pods on EKS using AzureDevOps. First I have installed kubectl and aws-iam-authenticator on my system(windows) and created a Kubernetes CLuster in AWS. To communicate with Cluster, I have updated kubeconfig using the following command  `aws eks --region us-east-2 update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name`. Now I have copied the updated config file and pasted in Azure DevOps New service Connection. while verifying the test connection, getting the below error.

> No user credentials found for a cluster in KubeConfig content. Make sure that the credentials exist and try again.

Below are my `kubeconfig` & `aws-auth-cm.yaml` files.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: *********
    server: https://*************.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:*********:cluster/testconnection
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:*********:cluster/testconnection
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:********:cluster/testconnection
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:**********:cluster/testconnection
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:*******:cluster/testconnection
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:*********:cluster/testconnection
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - testconnection
      command: aws

--- aws-auth-cm.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
 name: aws-auth
 namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
   - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::*********:role/eks_nodegroup
     username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
     groups:
       - system:bootstrappers
       - system:nodes
```

So, Could anyone guide me in the configurations which I have missed to establish the connection for EKS to AzureDevOps?

Comment: Can [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56915593/10910450) work for you?

Comment: Hi @ Lance Li-MSFT. I have already tried that process. but getting the following error ```Failed to parse Service Account secret The service account secret yaml does not contain 'data' field. Make sure that it is present and try again```. I have listed secrets using ```kubectl get secrets``` and described the secret, it has the data count as 3. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.